# OpenCV в Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
img = "yaroslav.jpg"

cv2.imshow('img',img)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite(r'res.jpg', img)
```

Установил Anacond'a 
 `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Импортирую библиотеку `import cv2`

Запускаю код, Вылезает ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

Comment: Так же устанавливал `pip install opencv-python` не знаю как с ней работать.

Comment: попробуйте удалить и поставить снова: `conda install opencv`

Comment: Удалил `conda uninstall -c conda-forge opencv` 

Установил `conda install opencv`

Не помогло

Comment: @MaxU установил, в `pip list` не пишет, что установлен opencv

Comment: @MaxU Ну так что?

Comment: Попробуйте pip3 install opencv-python